# What is status column meaning in Azure DevOps Repo history view?

Tags: azure-devops

Do someone know what do Status column mean in Repo History view?
I tried to look for explanation/documentation and couldn't find any.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a build/release status where that commit participates: [What information do you see on the commit details page?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commit-details?view=azure-devops#what-information-do-you-see-on-the-commit-details-page)

> Build status - You can also review the build status associated with
> the commit.
> [image]